# magicmock called several times but I can't assert called with

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

(Python 2.6)

I have a method:

```
def send_all(self, messages):
    for message in messages:
        queue.send(message)
```

I want to assert that `queue.send()` is called for each message

```
queue = MagicMock()
myobj= MyObject(queue)
myobj.send_all(test_messages)
for test_message in test_messages:
    queue.send.assert_called_once_with(test_message)
```

Each of the 55 messages in `test_messages` is unique. I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Expected to be called once. Called 55 times.
```

Comment: Didn't the error message make the problem clear? You're asserting that it was called *exactly* once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assert_called_once_with()` tests if your mock was called just *once*; don't use it to test for 55 different calls.

Instead, assert that those 55 calls were made with the [`mock.assert_has_calls()`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html) method:

```
queue.send.assert_has_calls([call(test_message) for test_message in test_messages])
```

This will test if that sequence of 55 calls is present; it doesn't limit the mock to having been called more times.

You could also test the [`mock.mock_calls` attribute](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.mock_calls):

```
assert queue.send.mock_calls == [call(test_message) for test_message in test_messages]
```

This will test for *exactly* those 55 calls.